# Jquery Chrome / Firefox removeClass inconsistencies

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have the following setup:

HTML:

```
<div class="col right-bar hidden">
  <span class="db-display-file-description">
    <!-- JS inserts html here -->
  </span>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="msg">File info is diplayed here...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.right-bar .overlay {
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:.3s;
  (...)
}
.right-bar.hidden .overlay {
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
  (...)
}
```

Then I add / remove the class "hidden", to hide the content (behind the overlay)

This works fine in chrome and opera (I din't test on IE, bcause I'm on Linux) but in FF (V. 39 Linux) I get a weird "blink" where it seems like the "hidden" class is added for a split second.

[Here is a video, where you can see the difference](https://vid.me/6I4o)

It most definetly isn't the html just not being there, because if you look closely, you can see the text appearing for a short moment.

I'm using the MaterializeCSS framework for styling, but this shouldn't matter here.

[EDIT] This just fixed itself. I went eating and when I came back, to show it my friend, it worked again. But I still want to know, what might have been happening there...

Comment: You did too much drugs and had hallucinations, mayBe?? ;)

Comment: No. I have a video that prooves it.... sadly.